# I get an associative array back as wel as a normal one with only one row from the db?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am getting values back and I pass it on to an ajaxfunction with `json_encode`

The strange thing is that I get `{0:val1, val1:val1,1:val2,val2:val2}`
back in firebug.  I expected to get an array rather than an object - i.e. `[val1, val2]`.

This is the query:

```
$q = "SELECT twitter_id,kindplaatje FROM krv_profielen WHERE twitter_id IS NOT NULL AND kindplaatje IS NOT NULL";
    $r = @mysql_query ($q,$dbc) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Fout: " . mysql_error($dbc));// Voer de query uit.
    if ($r) {

        if (mysql_num_rows($r) >= 1){
            $check = "ok";
            $data = mysql_fetch_array($r);
```

Is it a normal response?

Comment: Please refrain from using error suppression.

Comment: Downvoted. You haven't even said what your question is and everything you have included is normal.

Comment: heh, I voted myself down also,lol

Comment: @Richard I hope you're joking. If you did down-vote yourself it means you have multiple accounts which is a violation of SO policy.

Comment: @meagar - I think he was speaking in the proverbial sense.

Answer (score 3):

Because by default `mysql_fetch_array` returns a combined array that is indexed by number and key. See here: https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array

use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead.

Answer (score 2):

That is normal behaviour, ref https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array.

If you don't want that, you could add a second parameter to `mysql_fetch_array`, one of:

- MYSQL_ASSOC
- MYSQL_NUM
- MYSQL_BOTH

`MYSQL_BOTH` is default.

Comment: also thanks for the answer..thought I did something obscure, I don't trust myself anymore